# AngularJS updating scope data of another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS webapp where upon logging out I am redirected to the login page.  I wanted certain fields in the login page to be hidden based on some data passed back from the logout service in the backend.

Is there a way to do this ? I just need to update a variable in the login controller js but I am not sure how to do that from the logout controller js ?

Please help completely new to AngularJS!

Comment: What you're describing is incredibly broad and could be accomplished any number of ways.  If you could include the form you're working with, the fields you want hidden and some sample data to use, we could be more specific about our solutions.

Comment: Please enlightened me with one of the solution that you think will work. Thank you

Comment: The reason I've mentioned that this is too broad [can be found in this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323721/1079354).  If you have no way of demonstrating what constraints we're working with and whether or not one solution will *objectively* work for you, then it feels like a question that's entirely too broad and would result in a few different answers.  You should narrow down your criteria.

Comment: Use your angular app login service to store  user state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "value" option in your app

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
     .value('Config', null);
```

then you need to inject it in your controllers to make them communicate each others

```
.controller('controllerLogout', function(Config){
//do something that update Config
}

.controller('MainController' function(Config){
      //use Config here to bind it in a ng-show in HTML controlled by 
      //coontroller itself
}
```

Comment: I am sorry as I am very new to it, how exactly do you inject it ?

Comment: I have already done it :) look into the controller function argument :P
Now you can use the Config variable in both controllers as you want to

Comment: Doubt that a `value` will be helpful, you can't change it after run time

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use events for that.

In your logout controller do this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loggedOut',data);
```

And in you login controller

```
$scope.$on('loggedOut', function(event, data) {
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhTkaUpv4gGvfzNOTDfF?p=preview)